# Why no version number is needed in child POM?

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

This is part of a parent POM file:

```
 <properties>
    <hibernate.annotations.version>3.3.0.ga</hibernate.annotations.version>
    <hsqldb.version>1.8.0.7</hsqldb.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.annotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In Child POM, I have two questions:
1) why is it unnecessary to specify the version number for hibernate? 
2) Also, since hibernate is already specified in the parent POM as a dependency, why is it necessary to include it in child POM?

Thanks for explanation.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.optimize</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>simple-model</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Chapter 8 Simple Object Model</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Both questions can be answered by doing some research on `xxxManagement`. That's just how it works. The parent manages details about the dependency, giving the child the **option** to use that dependency. If the child doesn't need it, then it doesn't specify it in its pom. If it does need it, then it specifies it. The details are taken care of by the parent.

Comment: Have a look at [Introduction to the dependency mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). Show some informative use cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to this is cause the information like groupId, artifactId and version will be inherited by the child.
So the only need is usually to override the `artifactId`.

The second answer is simple cause via dependencyManagement you define what can be used in your childs but not really use it. If you deinfe a dependency in the dependencies block it will be really used.

And of course i can recommend to read the [documentation about dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) also i can recommend to read the [information about inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance).